# Check next line in bash

Tags: bash

I have a text like:

```
set 1 recovery 2 2
set 2 recovery 2 2
% ERROR Unknown error
set 3 recovery 2 2
set 4 recovery 2 2
% ERROR Unknown error
```

What I need is an output like:

```
set 1 recovery 2 2
set 2 recovery 2 2 ==> % ERROR Unknown error
set 3 recovery 2 2
set 4 recovery 2 2 ==> % ERROR Unknown error
```

I tried with awk and sed, but I'm failing. Could someone advice?
Thank you
Lucas

Comment: In `awk` you need to save the line in a variable. When you're processing a line, if it matches the error pattern, print the two lines together. Otherwise, print the saved line and save the current line in the variable.

Comment: Do you want to edit the file, or just produce the output? `ed` can do the former fairly easily using its `j` command, something `sed` seems to lack.

Comment: `I tried with awk and sed` Please post, what have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assumptions:

- there's at least one non-`ERROR` line before each `ERROR` line
- no 2 consecutive lines are `ERROR` lines

Sample data:

```
$ cat check.dat
set 1 recovery 2 2
set 2 recovery 2 2
% ERROR Unknown error
set 3 recovery 2 2
set 4 recovery 2 2
% ERROR Unknown error
```

One `awk` solution where we rely on `printf` to leave us on the current line until we explicitly tell it to print a newline (`\n`):

```
awk '
/ERROR/ { printf " ==> %s",$0 ; next }
        { printf "%s%s",nl,$0 ; nl="\n" }
END     { printf "\n" }
' check.dat
```

Where:

- `/ERROR/ ...` - if current line includes the string `ERROR` then append `==>` and the current line to the output; then skip rest of processing and go to the next line of input
- `{ printf "%s%s",nl,$0 ; nl="\n" }` - for lines w/out `ERROR` we print the line but first we print the `nl` variable; initially `nl=""` so for the first line of input we'll print to the first line of output; for successive `non-ERROR` lines we want `nl="\n"` so we can move the cursor off the end of the previous line and down to a new line before we print our `non-ERROR` line of text
- `END ...` - print one last new line characters (`\n`)

Results of running the above:

```
set 1 recovery 2 2
set 2 recovery 2 2 ==> % ERROR Unknown error
set 3 recovery 2 2
set 4 recovery 2 2 ==> % ERROR Unknown error
```